# How to find exact string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, find, include

I have an array:

and I trying to find the exactly string value with this

It works fine even if you are looking for "b" or "bt" *but* I would like to get result only when i'm looking for "btc" (exactly string value)

when I look for "b" or "bt" I want to get no result

```js
let coinsArray = [{
  symbol: "btc"
}]

let newStatus = coinsArray.filter(coin => coin.symbol.includes($(".InpSearchCoin").val()))

console.log(newStatus)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="InpSearchCoin" value="btc" />
```

Comment: Please add `status` array also

Comment: I made you a working snippet - you need to filter `coinsArray` and not status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use includes

```js
let coinsArray = [{
  symbol: "btc"
}]

$(".InpSearchCoin").on("input", function() {
  let symbol = coinsArray
    .filter(({symbol}) => symbol === this.value.toLowerCase())
  console.log(symbol)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="InpSearchCoin" value="" />
```